# How to implement gradient button bar in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, menu, interface-builder, sidebar

Some Cocoa applications (for instance, Mail and Automator) have a special control usually in the bottom of their window:

[alt text http://img150.imageshack.us/img150/9084/picture2vm3.png](http://img150.imageshack.us/img150/9084/picture2vm3.png)

Could you share the best practices of making the same action bar with standard images and popup buttons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want [BWToolkit](http://www.brandonwalkin.com/blog/2008/11/13/introducing-bwtoolkit/)