# Creating gradient button bar in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

My question is almost exactly the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540048/how-to-implement-gradient-button-bar-in-cocoa/), however the answer accepted (and only) answer was to use BWToolkit which is no longer an option for me because it isn't compatible with Xcode 4.

[image]

How can I create a similar bar in interface builder or programmatically, without BWToolkit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the source code of BWToolkit. It uses a custom NSView subclass to do the drawing. Cocoa hasn't got a built-in control for this.

Alternatively, you can use BWToolkit, but just the parts you need (BWAnchoredButtonBar, BWSplitView, BWAnchoredButtonBar and the NSColor and NSView categories). You don't need to include the entire framework in your app.